# $\lim_{x\to 0} {{\sqrt[x]{1-2x}}}$

Tags: calculus

How do I find the limit of this?
 $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} {{\sqrt[x]{1-2x}}}$$
I just have no idea where to start from.

Comment: $(1+\frac{a}{n})^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ L = \lim_{x \to 0} (1 - 2x)^{\frac{1}{x}}  $$

$$ \ln L = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1 - 2x)}{x} \overset{*}{=}  \lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{-2}{1-2x} = -2$$

$$ \Rightarrow L = e^{-2} $$

in $ * $ we used L'hopital